# CSS: Remove shadows on disabled HTML buttons

Tags: html, css, button, shadow

When disabling HTML buttons, a shadow gets added to the button text. I'm styling the buttons myself and I would like to only have the one colour (white) with NO shadow but I do not know how to do it efficiently.

My previous method was to leave it enabled and re-style the button's hover + active states and ignore the click vai Javascript. Told you, not very efficient!

http://jsfiddle.net/gLfMX/

EDIT: image to show the shadow (being viewed in IE9) + a zoomed version.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of fiddling, I've come to the conclusion it cannot be done with IE.

Since I handle all the button clicks using jQuery, I just ignore any button that has my CSS selected property applied. Granted it is probably not the most elegant solution, but it is cross-browser viewbale.

Thanks Nicole and danferth for the help.

Answer (score 9):

You already posted your own answer, but here's a bit more info.

From my experiments I've reached the same conclusion: on IE, you cannot change it from CSS. Here's why.

The colors of disabled buttons depend on what Windows is configured to show [for the "3D Objects" item in "Window Color and Appearance"](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-you-change-the-3d-objects-option-under/16963c64-adf4-449d-834b-71b52182027c) (under display settings).

The default colors of the disabled buttons are: text = `A0A0A0`, shadow = white. They may be different if the user changed the defaults (in Windows 7 you have to go into 'advanced settings' to do it), but almost everyone will have these. They were designed to fit the system default background color of a disabled button, which is `F4F4F4`.

[image]

My solution for this problem is to design the CSS so that at least for the default settings, under IE a disabled button will look OK - the best approach is to set the background when disabled to `F4F4F4`:

```
button[disabled], a[disabled] {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

If you're using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html) like me, you should do this instead:

```
.btn[disabled], .btn.disabled[disabled] {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

You can also add some conditional selector to enable this only for IE.

Answer (score 8):

add `border:none;` to get rid of the shadow [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danferth/gLfMX/1/)

Comment: Thanks but I'm talking about the shadow on the text inside the button, not the button border.

Comment: I'm only seeing that affect in `IE` possibly `jQuery` and `text-shadow:none;` is a solution.

Comment: @danferth: The problem is specific to IE 8 & 9 only. Note the 9. Not 10, not 11.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to remove the shadowing on the text inside the button.I was trying to get rid of my shadowing on my menu buttons.

After my top menus styling in CSS, I looked for my regular menu styling. 
Where ever you see the "text-shadow" styling first, there-in lies your problem. 
I found mine here:

```
#menu a{display:block;line-height:35px;padding:0 14px;text-decoration:none;color:
    #77778b;font-family:'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;text-shadow:none;}
```

My text shadow was set to #FFFFFF with some positioning applied. 
I simply removed this styling and bam, no more shadowing on my buttons.

Just look for wherever "text-shadow" is applied first in your menu CSS and set it to "text-shadow:none"

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
input[disabled] {
   border: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gLfMX/2/

This way you can specifically target the disabled input without worrying about interfering with the others.

Comment: Thanks but I'm talking about the shadow on the text inside the button, not the button border.

Comment: hmmm, I'm not seeing any text shadow in Firefox 9. If you do see one you could try the above selector with text-shadow: none;

Comment: Thanks Nicole. I've edited the post to show the shadow. The text-shadow selector doesn't seem to make a difference...

Comment: IE doesn't recognize text-shadow. I don't have IE handy to check, but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it "dims" disabled inputs and buttons. You may try declaring color: #fff; since IE is not actually shadowing it.